# google scripts run time slow then fast very intermittent

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc

This code runs fast(seconds) and then slow(2 minutes) very intermittent. The db is sql server.

```
function test(){
  let resultsArray =[];
  let t = 0;
  let rows = []
  cs = this.conn.prepareCall("{call counts(?,?)}");
  cs.setString(1,'download' );
  cs.setString(2,'pwg' );
  let rs = cs.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()){
     resultsArray.push(new Array(13));
      for (var col = 1; col < 13; col++) { 
        resultsArray[t][col]= rs.getString(col);
      };
      t++;
     
    
  };
rs.close();
cs.close();
}
```

Only requesting 200 rows . I debugged it and the data retrieval is instant. I can't find any reasons why the time difference is so drastic.
I also tried run without a store procedure like this and the same problem.

```
const sql = "SELECT 
Loc1,Inv1,Status1,Loc2,Inv2,Status2,loc3,Inv3,Status3,Loc4,Inv4,Status4,ProductID FROM 
products WHERE (catagory=?) And (Loc1>'' Or Loc2>'' Or Loc3>'' Or Loc4>'')"

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,Jdbc.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
 Jdbc.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);  
 stmt.getResultSetConcurrency();
stmt.setString(1, catagory)
 
const results = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Jdbc can be that way.  It depends upon the number of users I suppose.